# What's up with the Chafetz Chaim yeshiva guys?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, yeshiva-school, chofetz-chaim

I know they learn a lot slower, dress a little flashier, and learn more mussar than in most mainstream yeshivos, but can someone specify exactly what is the philosophy of the Chafetz Chaim yeshiva system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a Wikipedia [sub-entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivas_Rabbeinu_Yisrael_Meir_HaKohen#Characteristics) on this topic that someone who's been involved with this movement for a while told me is impressively accurate.

Answer (score 11):

I went to a Chafetz Chaim Yeshiva and here are the basic Hashkafot (to my understanding):

- Gadlus HaAdom- meaning that the person has a lot of potential and should have self respect for themselves by dressing nicely.
- The high school system has a very long day to prepare the students for the long day of Bet Midrash (the Yeshiva expects kids to go to Bet Midrash and become Rabbanim in the long run, after 14 years of Yeshiva).
- They look at the Parasha with one Mefaresh and make something called a "Shmuz- a talk" it is a really an ethical usually 20-25 sermon discussing real life issues.
- They are very into the study of Mussar specifically using the Messilat Yesharim or the Orhot Tzaddikim. Their Derech is based on the Salanter path.
- They take very long in their sugyot because the claim they have a better grasp of the Gemara that way, while other Yeshivas just skim through the pages using all-types of Mefarshim without any Toelet.

I personally believe this is a very good Hashkafa, probably the best ashkenaz hashkafa out there.